# How do i make a link appear in a textbox, and let the button save it in a database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, google-chrome

I'm about to create a google extension, where i simply wanna make something like a bookmark app. Just to learn.

I did now fall over my first issue, when i could not find no help for this, so i'll try here:

- I right now have a simple form looking like this:

  `<div class="form">
      URL: <input type="text" name="url"><br>
  </div>`

What i want it to do, is i want it to display the exact link where people opens my app! [Picture](http://i59.tinypic.com/193x1f.png)

When that is done, and people clicks the save button, i want the link to be stored in a mysql database. How am i supposed to do that? Any answar will be taken with a smile.

UPDATE! I found out that i can't use php as file format for the extension. It have to be .html. I can include javascript, so if that's possible, i would like to know how.

Comment: I dont understand, do you want the input box to display a desired URL or do you want to add an entry to mysql with php? And why is google chrome tagged?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer.
i want the input to show a URL. lets say i went to youtube.com/songlink, and clicked on my extension on google chrome (thats why it's tagged), i would love to be able to save the exact link in my mysql db and show it on a seperated website. just like bookmark :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you retrieve your link, so I'll skip that part and just assign it to a variable...

```
<?php $url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'; ?>
<div class="form">
    URL: <input type="text" name="url" value="<?php echo (isset($url))? $url:''; ?>"><br>
</div>
```

To save by just a `onblur` or `onkeyup` you can use `AJAX`.

If you want to click a submit button, then you just write an if condition to save it to your db like so:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['url'])) {
        // do insert into database here...
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you. So i understand the most of it, and will try from here! Helpful